# Trying to count the total number of rows from a 0-d array Python

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

I have a task to count to update a `variable = data_dict`, into a new `variable = data_dict_cleaned` (with some rows deleted), for this reason I turned `data_dict_cleaned` to an array to delete some rows. This is when I encountered a problem as I need to count the number of data records from the improved variable(`data_dict_cleaned`). I need a way to to count the number of data records from "`data_dict_cleaned`" as normal iteration doesn't work (cannot iterate 0-d array)

Thank you for your time and effort.[image: ][1]]
[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Please include your code and error message as formatted text in the question.

Comment: Don't use `nditer` to iterate on an array.  That's for advanced users only.  If you want to iterate with an index use `for i in range(...):` looping.

Comment: @hpaulj I tried the for loop but it returns TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

Comment: is it possible to turn back the "data_dict_cleaned" into list form, and then iterate it?

Comment: A 0d array is like a scalar; there's nothing to iterate on.  Make sure you understand the nature of that array - it shape and dtype, and it's contents.  Don't assume - verify.

Comment: Why is this thing even an array at all? It sounds like you called `array` on some dict without understanding what that means.